# Query nested data from Firebase Real-time database Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I have the structure in the image below and I want to get the whole data from the node "aaa1234" querying by "id_Usuario". How can I do that query?

[image: This is my structure]

I tried:

```
DatabaseReference root = database.getReference().child("Eventos").child("participantes");
Query query = root.orderByChild("id_Usuario").equalTo(2);
```

Just to be more clear, the "aaa1234" is a custom key, so it will be different in the next node.

Comment: You're storing the user ID as a number, so shouldn't have quotes around the value in `equalTo`. So: `.equalTo(2)`

Comment: Thx for that, I missed it, but still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two mistakes.

The first one is a typo, which I already marked in my comment. You're storing the user ID as a number, so shouldn't have quotes around the value in equalTo. So: `.equalTo(2)`

The second mistake is in the way you try to query:

```
DatabaseReference root = database.getReference().child("Eventos").child("participantes");
```

This will create a reference to the non-existing child `Eventos/participantes`. What you want to do instead is query `Eventos`, but then against property `participantes/id_Usuario`. So

```
DatabaseReference root = database.getReference().child("Eventos");
Query query = root.orderByChild("participantes/id_Usuario").equalTo(2);
```