# Can i search on child of child of child in firebase-android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have structure like that :

```
users ->
    userId1 ->
        info -> 
           userPhone :11111
    userId2 -> 
        info ->
            userPhone : 22222
```

How can i query on userPhone with this architecture

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I think this may be a different question. The property to search on is nested at a fixed path under `info`, which is possible, but requires some additional syntax for searching. Typically `ref.orderByChild("info/userPhone").equalTo("22222")`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43929230/query-nested-data-from-firebase-real-time-database-android

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for your answer

Comment: @RobertHarvey try to understand the question first, it's different question!!

Comment: Does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43929230/query-nested-data-from-firebase-real-time-database-android) answer it?  `DatabaseReference root = database.getReference().child("Eventos").child("participantes");`

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes, this : ref.orderByChild("info/userPhone").equalTo("22222") worked for me