# Prism7 wpf projects not loading because of version tags? how to fix

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, prism

I downloaded Prism 7 from Github and a number of projects will not load. The reason is given when compiling the code is this error:

> C:\plural\Prism-master\Source\Wpf\Prism.Wpf\Prism.Wpf.csproj : error 
>   : Expected "$(IS_PREVIEW)" to evaluate to a boolean instead of "", in
>   condition " '$(PRISM_RELEASE)' == '' And '$(PRISM_WPF_VERSION)' == ''
>   And '$(IS_PREVIEW)' ". 
>   C:\plural\Prism-master\Source\Wpf\Prism.Wpf\Prism.Wpf.csproj

How do I fix this?

Version 6.0 never gave this problem.

The following projects will not load in Prism 7

```
Prism.Wpf

Prism.Unity.Wpf

Prism.StructureMap.Wpf

Prism.DryIoc.Wpf

Prism.Ninject.Wpf
```

Comment: Yeah, that is aggravating, isn't it?  I had problems initially building version 6 as well.  Unfortunately, it looks like they took the Slack channel for Prism down; I think maybe Brian Lagunas got tired of answering people's beginner questions (Prism is a great library, but it's not the easiest thing to grasp initially).

Comment: Note that you don't actually have to build the Github repository in order to use Prism.  Just get the [Nuget package.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43929230/query-nested-data-from-firebase-real-time-database-android)  Unfortunately, I don't understand their versioning scheme well enough to modify the csproj files so that the solution will build.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/1652

The Prism 7 repository requires a number of dependencies that are not part of NuGet.  In particular, you need **.NET Core 3.0**, which you can get from [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.0).

Because (as of this writing) it is a preview release, you have to *opt in* in Visual Studio.  You do this by selecting **Tools/Options/Projects and Solutions/.NET Core** from the Visual Studio menu bar.  This process is described in detail here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gIlfHtqgKk8&feature=youtu.be

If you haven't done so yet, you need to make sure your Visual Studio 2017 installation is at least version 15.9.3.  If you don't have this version or higher, you can upgrade your installation from [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/update-visual-studio?view=vs-2017).  Versions earlier than this will not have the opt-in checkbox mentioned above.

When you install Visual Studio, make sure the **Universal Windows Platform** feature is checked.

Finally, you will need the **Windows 10 Creators Update**, which you can get from [this page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10).  Just click the Update button.